# Count how many times a value appears per month in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following time series with hourly data of several years:

```
    local time         ghi mean
0       2013-01-01 00:00:00 0.0
1       2013-01-01 01:00:00 0.0
2       2013-01-01 02:00:00 -9999
3       2013-01-01 03:00:00 0.0
4       2013-01-01 04:00:00 0.0
..         ...          ...
8754    2016-12-31 18:00:00 427.5
8755    2016-12-31 19:00:00 194.9
8756    2016-12-31 20:00:00 -9999
8757    2016-12-31 21:00:00 237.6
8758    2016-12-31 22:00:00 -9999
8759    2016-12-31 23:00:00 0.0
```

And I need to count how many times the value -9999 appears and group by year and month.The desired output would be something similar to:

```
    local time     ghi mean
0    2013-01   1
..         ...          ...
8    2016-12   2
```

I tried:

```
df.groupby(df["local time"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')).df['ghi mean'].value_counts()[-9999]
```

But got:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'df'
```

Comment: I think you just wanted `df.groupby(df["local time"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'))['ghi mean'].value_counts()[-9999]` Column selection is just square braces for groupby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boolean select, groupby sum should give you what you need much easily

if `df['ghi mean']` is a float or integer

```
  (df['ghi mean']==-9999).groupby(df['local time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')).sum()
```

if you made `df['ghi mean']`a string then

```
(df['ghi mean']=='-9999.0').groupby(df['local time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')).sum()
```

Comment: Worked, thanks !!!!

Comment: Please upvote, if happy

Comment: How can i exclude the months with 0 as result or only show the months with any result different than 0 as output

Comment: `df[df['ghi mean']!=0]` or  `df[df['ghi mean'].ne(0)]` filter out those not equal to zero